# Hamburger menu won't expand on mobile

Tags: jquery, menu

I've seen discussion here about this issue, but I can't make it work for me. This works fine on my browser, but the menu won't expand when tested on a phone. It won't react to the touch for some reason, and therefore won't expand. Any idea how to fix it?

```
$('.hamburger').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.menu').toggleClass('slide-down');

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to show your full code? There might be other things blocking or interfering with your current one?

Comment: `touchstart` not the right event. `:/`

Comment: I posted what I hope is just the relevant code here: http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/ezZEVb

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, it appears to work for me with tap instead of touchstart.

```
$('.hamburger').on('click tap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu').toggleClass('slide-down');
});
```

Also, make sure you're including jQuery-mobile and not just jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `This works fine on my browser` - This assures the OP uses jQuery.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It ensures they're using jQuery, but not that they're using jQuery Mobile, which I believe they need for touch events (though I'm not 100% certain on that.)

Comment: Yes, you may be right... `:)`

Comment: Added jquery mobile and that didn't work for me either. Menu still won't open on touch. It works fine on my browser, but not on mobile. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @NJeffries Did you also change touchstart to tap?

Comment: @Cathony Yes, I did. I am using: 'click tap'    It seems that when I include code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5 it disables clicking in my browser Dev Tools. It doesn't work on mobile or browser with that in my <head>.

Comment: @NJeffries Just a thought, but have you tried using slideToggle instead of adding a class to manually change the height? For whatever reason, your original code doesn't seem to be working in chrome for me, but if I replace toggleClass with slideToggle('slow') it does.

Comment: @Cathony  That works for me, but not on my phone. Is this a jQuery thing? Would I have more luck trying to figure out a pure JavaScript solution? My js is poor but I'm sure I could figure something out.

Comment: Oddly enough, with slideToggle, it seems to work on my phone, so I'm not sure if jQuery is to blame. Which mobile browser are you using?